# SSRS Column Visibility

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-expression

I am looking for a solution in creating a parameter on column names.
Here is my situation:
I have 5 columns, ColumnA,ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD and ColumnE. I need a Parameter on this column names, so that when I select ColumnA data in ColumnA should be populated and other 4 columns should be empty (other 4 columns should not be hidden its just the data in the 4 columns should be null). Like the same way if I select ColumnC, then ColmnA,B,D,E should be empty but ColumnC should populate data. Also I need a selection on multiple values, for example If I select ColumnA&C then they should populate data but other 3 columns should be empty.
Above is my problem, please help me out with this situation. Its been long time I am trying to figuring out how to solve this issue.
Please suggest some ideas.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is actually quite simple. Just add an IFF expression as follows for each textbox in your columns

```
=IIF(Parameters!Column.Value = "A", "",Fields!cloumnAdetail.Value) for A
=IIF(Parameters!Column.Value = "B", "",Fields!cloumnBdetail.Value) for B...
```

So basically if they select Column A parament then column A values will appear, but all other column values will disappear, they will be set to "". But the columns will still appear

There might be a better way. but this will work. It should also work with multiple value parameter.

Comment: Hi, Its working when single parameter value is passed, but i am not able to see any change when I am trying to pass multiple values.

Comment: I think its not changing with multiple parameters passed because parameters!column.Value is being set to 2 values instead of either A, B, C ... you may have to create a more elaborate IIF statement that covers multiple situations. perhaps 3 IIF statements for each column, for example

`=IIF(Parameters!Column.Value = "A" AND Parameters!Column2.Value = "B", "",Fields!cloumnAdetail.Value)`


.....


`=IIF(Parameters!Column.Value = "A" AND Parameters!Column2.Value = "C", "",Fields!cloumnAdetail.Value)`

And so on

Comment: Be sure to Accept my answer if it helped you appropriately. (Click the check mark below the rating)

Answer (score 0):

It might be solve your problem, please try this below expression.

=IIF(Filter(parameters!Column.Value,"A",true,CompareMethod.Text).Length>0,Fields!cloumnAdetail.Value,"") For Column A

same above for remaining columns.